# Find all words between % and % in full text?

Tags: php, regex

i need to find each word between % characters in a text.

For Example: there are some words like %NAME% or %SURNAME%, and i need to find the exact word.

I perfomed preg_match_all, but i can't figure out with the regex. Can someone help me?

```
preg_match_all('/\b\%(\w+)\%\b/', $format, $keywords);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `preg_match_all('/%(\w+)%/', $format, $keywords);`

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/uW5yV1/1)

Comment: This answer is identical to the first answer provided by @Toto. I'd prioritize the first answer.

Comment: @stribizhev My mistake.. toto's answer was posted just seconds before mine and i missed to see it..

Comment: @karthikmanchala: I do not say anything against, I myself have been in such situations. It is more a hint to MTS.

Comment: @karthikmanchala: Don't worry, It's OK to have the same answer, especially when it's right :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the word boundaries, they have no use here:

```
preg_match_all('/%(\w+)%/', $format, $keywords);
```

Comment: Correct, but, actually, I'd say `\b` does harm here preventing some valid matches, not "have no use". Just an illustration: https://regex101.com/r/oK4jN6/4

Comment: @stribizhev: True, but OP wants to match word between % and %, whatever is present before and after.